# saving JSON to mySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need to save an array of data to MySQL. However the array is not fixed in length.

The array could be something like:

```
array(key1 => value1)
```

or like

```
array(key1 => value1, key2=> value2)
```

and so on.

If it was a fixed length array then JOIN could solve the problem.
I'm thinking about saving it as a JSON string

the data table would be like:

```
id -- context -- content (JSON Str)
```

Is this a good idea? are there better ways to do this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to consider a separate table, which will be much easier to query later on.

```
data [table]
- id
- context

data_items [table]
- data_id [foreign_key]
- key
- value
```

Insert as many data_items records as you have in an array, linking to one data record.

Comment: in addition, another table will be needed to act as an intermediary between the context and the keys, to be able to tell which key belongs to which row.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, the data_id already provides that. If you're struggling to put it all together, post a new question with some example data that needs to be organized.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a good idea to store your array data in JSON. It is more portable that serialize, and, in my experience, better at handling UTF-8 characters.

FTR I generally try not to store huge amounts of 'content' data within the database, but opt for some sort of needle/haystack file storage like MongoDB.

Comment: Portability is not an issue. UTF-8 is not an issue. Both can be done wrong in any way in any case, with or without JSON strings.

Comment: Portability can be an issue if non PHP code is used to access the 'content' data. And as I mentioned in my post, JSON, in my experience is better at handling utf-8 characters than serialize. The OP did not mention which type of data will be stored in array, which is confusing, b/c others assume database normalization, where I assumed data storage.

Comment: Well, the alternative is to properly store the data in multiple rows and connect them via ID references. That will work with any encoding, any programming language.

Comment: Again, what data? No example was given. If the OP updates to include data which indicates normalization, I'll delete this response.

Answer (score 1):

If you do know for sure that you do not need to access any data inside the json string, and you will never try to access any row based on this info, then storing it as a json string might work.

Usually it is a better idea to normalize the data with a second table. Or switch to a NOSQL database solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly store serialized data in a serialization format like PHP's serialization format or JSON.  My only question is whether you need to access any data in this serialized array (i.e. query against this data).  If you are always going to be querying against an id of some sort, this should work fine.  If however you need to actually work with that data within the database, you might want to consider a NoSQL solution for working with non-structured data.